# Using a script to notify when a Personal Storage device was inserted into Mac

Tags: macos, bash, script

I'm new to Macintosh. Is it possible in macOS to create a certain "script" that will notify both the user and the admin whenever a flash drive/personal storage device is connected to the Mac

Comment: Actually managed a workaround, What I'm thinking now is, How can I run the script that I created when the flash drive was inserted.

Answer (score 2):

Although not a script, this tiny bit of Swift code, will report any disk insertions either physical or virtual. It may be of assistance to you:

```
import Foundation
import DiskArbitration

let session = DASessionCreate(CFAllocatorGetDefault().takeRetainedValue())

DARegisterDiskAppearedCallback(
    session!,
    nil,
    { (disk, context) in
        if let name = DADiskGetBSDName(disk) {
            print("Disk inserted: " + String(cString: name))
        }
},
    nil)

DASessionScheduleWithRunLoop(session!, CFRunLoopGetMain(), CFRunLoopMode.defaultMode.rawValue)

RunLoop.main.run()
```

Comment: Appreciate your help bro, I'm more into script. Tho I want to try the code you gave. i don't have idea how can I run that.

Comment: You should be able to run the command "swift" from the command-line, and macOS should offer to install command-line utilities for developers. After that, you'll be able to run the command "swift", and just copy and paste this into the prompt you get to try it out.

Comment: or just run `xcode-select --install` first

Comment: I already tried the code and got and error`repl.swift:10:12: error: initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'UnsafePointer<Int8>'
        if let name = DADiskGetBSDName(disk) {
           ^
repl.swift:16:60: error: use of unresolved identifier 'CFRunLoopMode'
DASessionScheduleWithRunLoop(session!, CFRunLoopGetMain(), CFRunLoopMode.defaultMode.rawValue)
                                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
repl.swift:18:1: error: use of unresolved identifier 'RunLoop'
RunLoop.main.run()
^~~~~~~`

Comment: @jquiambao what version if macOS are you running?

Comment: OS X EL Capitan  | 10.11.6

Comment: That might be it. I’m running 10.12